# Geolocation error with google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So,here is the page: http://codepen.io/sterg/full/NAVWay/ 
It works fine with Mozzila and Edge but it doesn't work with Chrome.
Any ideas why this happens?

Here is the javascript I use to get the geolocation data(latitude longitude):

```
$(document).ready(function() {



if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    //$(".test1").append("latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
    var ur="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+position.coords.latitude+"&lon="+position.coords.longitude+"&appid=18c7e2b6b0150a8f1d2c6b946e065697";
        $.getJSON(ur, function(json) {
       // $(".test2").append(JSON.stringify(json));
        $(".location").append(json.name+","+json.sys.country);
        $(".tempe").html(   (json.main.temp-273.15).toFixed() + " &#8451; " );

        $(".option2").click(function(){
        $(".tempe").html(   ((json.main.temp-273.15)*(9/5)+32).toFixed() + " &#8457; " );
        });
        $(".option1").click(function(){
        $(".tempe").html(   (json.main.temp-273.15).toFixed() + " &#8451; " );
        });

        if(json.weather[0].main=="Clear"){
            $('body').css({
          'background': 'url(http://eskipaper.com/images/sunny-day-4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed',
          '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
          '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
          '-o-background-size': 'cover',
          'background-size': 'cover',
          'font-family':'Baloo Paaji',
           'color': '#7a5cfe',
            'font-size':'30px'

        });
        }else if (json.weather[0].main=="Clouds") {
            $('body').css({
          'background': 'url(http://constantine.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a7fc3be9970b01bb08d49380970d-pi) no-repeat center center fixed',
          '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
          '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
          '-o-background-size': 'cover',
          'background-size': 'cover',
           'font-family':'Baloo Paaji',
           'color': '#7a5cfe',
            'font-size':'30px'
        });

        }else if (json.weather[0].main=="Rain") {
            $('body').css({
          'background': 'url(https://images4.alphacoders.com/235/235564.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed',
          '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
          '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
          '-o-background-size': 'cover',
          'background-size': 'cover',
            'font-family':'Baloo Paaji',
           'color': '#7a5cfe',
            'font-size':'30px'
        });
        }

//https://images4.alphacoders.com/235/235564.jpg
//http://constantine.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a7fc3be9970b01bb08d49380970d-pi
        });

  });


}



});
```

Comment: Did you bother to look at the Javascript console? *getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.*

Comment: Is there any other option though?

Comment: Also in mozilla and edge it works just fine so..

Comment: So what? Google has added what they believe is a security improvement, the other browsers haven't (yet?).

Comment: The error message has a link to a web page with more information. Was it helpful? SO wouldn't let me put the link in my comment.

Comment: @stop I've seen few people (using openweathermap API also) use http://ip-api.com/json in order to locate the IP of the client (which has less accuracy, but it's enough for city level geolocation)